# Linear transformation: projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1-x_2+x_3=0\}$ find the standard matrix for the projection on $V$

Then $S=span[(1,1,0),(-1,0,1)]$

So, I know that I have to evaluate the cannonical vectors $e_1=(1,0,0) ,e_2=(0,1,0),e_3=(0,0,1)$

But how can I calculate $proj_S (e_1)$, $proj_S(e_2)$ and $proj_S(e_3)$?

Thanks!

Comment: What's "\gen"? ${}{}{}$

Comment: V is spanned = gen

Answer (score 0):

Let $v=(1,-1,1)^T$.
Note that $V=\{ x| \langle v, x \rangle =0 \}$, so one way of obtaining a projection on to $V$ is to 'follow' $v$ until you 'hit' $V$.

That is, $Px = x-\alpha v$, where $\alpha$ is chosen so that
$\langle v, Px \rangle =0 $.

This gives
$\langle v, x \rangle - 3\alpha =0$, or $\alpha = {1 \over 3} \langle v, x \rangle$.

Then $Px = x-{1 \over 3} \langle v, x \rangle v = x-{ 1 \over 3} v v^T x = (I - { 1 \over 3} v v^T) x$. Multiplying and adding gives the one projection (the orthogonal one) onto $V$.